# Operator overload = and const reference

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, constants

I'm trying to construct a class for colors in C++,
this is not an homework is just that I'm still struggling with references and const.

--Color.h

```
class Color{
private:
    double r;
    double g;
    double b;
    double a;
public:
    //constructor, getters and setters...
    Color& operator =(Color& other_color); //(1)
}
```

--Color.cpp

```
Color& operator=(Color& other_color){
     this->r = other_color.get_r(); //line 41
     this->b = other_color.get_b();
     //and so on...
     return *this;
}
```

like this it works fine but I heard one has to put a const to avoid that by fault the object will be modified by the assignement operation, so one has to declare the other object as const. Like this:

```
Color& operator =(Color const& other_color); //(2)
```

but it gives me this errors:

```
/Users/../color.cpp:41: error: passing 'const Color' as 'this' argument of 'float Color::get_r()' discards qualifiers
```

so here is my question...

what is happening here? second what would happen if I don't declare **other_color** as const? what are the possible errors?

PS.: little bonus question:
I want to pass my variable to the opengl glColor4v(colorx.return_rgba()) returning the array [r,g,b,a] of the class Color. This:

```
float* Color::return_rgba(){
    float  rgba[4] = {this->r, this->g, this->b, this->a};
    return rgba;
}
```

won't work because rgba won't be in scope anymore after the return so it will be deleted and my pointer will point to not initialized adresses, damn...

Comment: I edited the question the line 41 is where I putted the comment

Comment: BTW, you don't really need to overload `operator=`. That is only needed if you want a different behavior than the default memberwise assignment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> passing 'const Color' as 'this' argument of 'float Color::get_r()' discards qualifiers

This means you have to take it further. `get_r` is probably declared as

```
float get_r()
```

and to make it work (const-correctly), you should make it

```
float get_r() const
```

> second what would happen if I don't declare other_color as const?

You would be unable to assign from `const`-qualified `Color`s. You usually want to be able to use `const` objects, among other as source of assignment. Moreover, it makes the intent not to modify the source clear to the reader of the code.

> I want to pass my variable to the opengl glColor4v(colorx.return_rgba()) returning the array [r,g,b,a] of the class Color.

Return a special "vehicle" that would contain the array and convert automatically to `float*`. Something along

```
struct ColorQuadruplet
{
  float data_[4];
  // add initialization and such here
  operator float*() { return data_; }
};

ColorQuadruplet Color::get_rgba() const
{
  ColorQuadruplet ret;
  // fill ret
  return ret;
}
```

Comment: you're fast, and I think you answered the question. That means that I have to set all the methods that I intend to use in a constant reference as constant..?

Comment: Yes. Even more, you want all methods that aren't meant to modify the object as const.

Comment: @Pella86 : Yes, this concept is known as [const-correctness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Const-correctness).

Comment: great! thank you! further question, if I don't use const... never, what are the problems I can have?

Comment: @Pella86: There are two faces of this question. (1) If you never used `const` in any of the sources you give to your compiler, the resulting program would behave just the same. Some people say "if you don't want to modify something, you just don't modify it", these don't need const. However, I think it is a possibility to use C++'s type system for a useful purpose... so I'd use const. (2) You can't avoid using const objects in some contexts ... eg. `std::set` exposes its contents as `const` objects.

Comment: I never used the const correctness, I'm coming from the python environment... but anyway I'm according with the second one :D, is a little more work, but I'm according with you for the 2nd point! Thank you for everything!

Answer (score 2):

You have two choices here. One is for your `operator=` to directly access to the members of the source object:

```
Color &operator=(Color const &other) { 
    r = other.r;
    g = other.g;
    b = other.b;
    a = other.a;
}
```

The other (which you probably want to do in any case, if you insist on having accessors for the color components at all) is to const-qualify the accessors you've written:

```
double get_r() const { return r; }
               ^^^^^
```

The `const` here is the part I've added that you apparently don't have.

Edit: as far as passing the values to glColor goes, I'd consider a small front-end something like this:

```
gl_color(Color const &c) { 
    glColor4d(c.r, c.g, c.b, c.a);
}
```